# Directories mess

Tags: administer

Should the content of the admin page Diretories be, litteraly:

```
    CiviCRM » Administer CiviCRM
Settings - Upload Directories

You may configure these upload directories using absolute paths or path variables. Path Variables
[cms.root]
```

On a otherwise white basic html-page, whith plain html navigation? If so, why? If not, how do I fix this eye sore?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know what a page should look like, you can compare against one of the demo sites - eg http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/setting/path?reset=1

It should look something like this:
[image: settings upload directories image]

Is that just that one page showing wrongly, or others too?

Comment: It's just that page  - everything else looks fine.